# RegEx for specified string length range : XSD attribute element

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xml-attribute

I'm trying to restrict an attribute element of a schema to be between 3 and 20 characters long, but I'm getting an error saying my RegEx is invalid:

```
<xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-Z]{3,20}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly here? Specific error is `"Range end code point is less than the start end code point"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a-Z` is the invalid range, you should use the lowercase `z` instead `a-z`

```
 <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z]{3,20}" />
```

Note that `a` ascii value is 97 and `Z` is 90 so you were actually defining an interval from 97 to 90 => `end-point code is lower than the start-point code`

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even notice that second z was uppercase, thanks for lending me your eyes and pointing that out for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `xs:maxLength` and `xs:minLength`:

```
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:minLength value="3"/>
  <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
</xsd:restriction>
```